# React Native Image tag induces server response fail

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having troubles adding an image in a view :

[Path seems to be the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6MmV.png)

In the expo web page i get the error : Unable to resolve "./components/kesra.jpg" from "components\search.js"

My image tab is like that :

```
<Image source={require('./components/kesra.jpg')}></Image>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Judging from the error, `search.js` is in the components folder. If that's where your image is, too, try `require('./kesra.jpg')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you put the wrong slash in path.

In

```
components\search.js
```

It should be

```
components/search
```

Try this and see if it works.

Edit:: Seems like I misunderstood the question. It seems like your image is in components folder. That is the same folder as your search.js. So the path of to your image should be like-

```
./kesra.jpg
```

Comment: Still got the same issue. But I think that's the correct way to do it because the imports -which are working- are written like that